# PHPStorm Configuration: How to remove background color on embedded html?

Tags: javascript, php, phpstorm

I find this "code highlighting" very annoying. Can someone show me how to disable it on PHPStrom, and perhaps explain why this happens?

Here's an image of my Js/Jquery code on PHPStorm IDE:
[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the WebStorm preferences go to `Editor » Color & Fonts » General` choose `Injected language fragment` from the list and turn off `Background` chackbox.

It's hard to answer _why it happens) - it's just a preference. Maybe someone prefers to see injected code (the code in language other than the main one used in given file) clearly marked. For me, it's also a distraction, I have just turned it off inspired by your question ;)

Answer (score 1):

That's [Language Injection](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Language+Injections+%28mix-ins%29+in+PhpStorm) in action.

You cannot disable it -- ATM language injections in JavaScript [cannot be disabled](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-1475).

But you can remove/change background color at `Settings (Preferences on Mac) | Editor | Colors & Fonts | General`.